# How to add your code to Android application?

Tags: java, android

I have an application that I want to modify by adding my own little code.
In many sites, I looked through the methods of decompilation, editing, recompilation, but I still could not find the answer to my question.
**How can I add my Java code to a compiled Android application?**

Comment: If that application is written by you then I expect you to have that project. If the app is designed by somebody else and you want to add some functionality on their app, then it's simply impossible.

Comment: You cannot add extra code to an application that has been compiled, unless the original developers have added the functionality to do so - which as the previous comment says - most people don't do it, as it's a major security risk! You additionally need to be careful about violating copyrights too.

Answer (score 0):

WDYM? Android apps are often obfuscated before compiling which makes it very hard to understand the code.
Your question doesn't make sense to me. If you decompiled it, just open the files with any IDE and edit them?! You said you read about editing and recompilation... Well then, why cant you edit?

Note: What are you trying to do? If it isnt an offline game, then it's illegal (probably the terms of service of the app state that) and if you are trying to increase your coins or something there are simpler ways to do that. Learn about app development first and then try something more diffictult like this.